# GPU gtx 1080 Ti not detected on Intel S2600CW2R Server Board

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, ubuntu-server

So I'm building a deep learning machine with 1 Xeon e5-2620v4 and 2 gtx 1080ti on top of an Intel S2600CW2R server board..

I bought it at a local store, and ask them to assemble my system. When it arrived, the system won't even POST or giving me any output on the display, just blank(tried to plug the cable to the GPU card and the onboard connector, results are the same). After doing some research, I found that the local store misplaced the GPU on the wrong PCIe slot. I fix this, get the system POST, and the display works(plugged the display cable to the onboard display connector) and install ubuntu 16.04 server.

After that, I tried to "lspci | grep NVIDIA" and the output gave me nothing. So I thought it must be the drivers that need to be installed. I installed the "nvidia-381" package from "ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa", reboot the system, tried to "lspci | grep NVIDIA" again, still nothing. Then I tried " nvidia-smi" but the output says ""NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running"

So I jump into conclusion that somehow, the motherboard cannot detect any of the plugged GPU card. How can I resolve this issue ? Have anybody encountered the same issue ?

Note:

- I Tried to plug the display cable into one of the GPU card, blank
  screen.
- Already checked the BIOS setup, "Add-in Display" option greyed out.
- Tried the GPU on another system, work like a charm
- Tried to boot from legacy mode and UEFI mode, results nothing.
- Tried to update the BIOS firmware, still no results.
- I'm aware of the trickiness on how the PCIe lane works on this
  particular platform(LGA2011). The datasheet mentioned that the PCI/e
  slot 1 - 2 are linked to CPU2 socket, and PCI/e slot 3-6 are bound to
  CPU1 socket. Therefore, if I want to plug my GPU1 on PCIe slot 1 and
  GPU2 on PCIe slot 4, I must have 2 CPUs installed

Comment: What is the output from `lspci | grep VGA`?

Comment: @Ray The output is "....MATROX=....something" . And I believe it's the integrated display adapter. Sorry I can't remember the whole line, i'm nowhere near the system right now. But the output is just that one line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the exact same boat as you.

You mention you're only using one CPU, but have you connected power to both CPU sockets? According to [this](https://communities.intel.com/thread/96858), you need to power both.

My PSU only has one EATX power cable so I can't test it until I get another.